# Maximize sum-distance for integer array

Tags: algorithm

Given an integer array A, return the maximum possible sum-distance between two elements. The sum-distance is defined as `A[i] + A[j] + (i - j)` for i > j

For example with `A = [8, 2, 4, 9, 5, 8, 0, 3, 8, 2]` the max sum-distance is 24 achieved with i=0 and j=8

An O(**n<sup>2</sup>**) solution is trivial. Is there any O(**n**) solution (where **n** is the length of the array)?

Comment: Sure, as `max(A[i] + i for i in range(len(A)) + max(A[j] - j for j in range(len(A)))`. Then I watch you edit in the absolute value or the restriction that `i < j`, and then I go find the duplicate.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Does this even make a difference? It seems like if i - j is negative, there is a better solution with i and j swapped. In that case I think we can still mark it as a duplicate, if it's not too much effort finding one

Comment: @NiklasB. Well, was asked before but not answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31139032/in-an-array-find-the-largest-sum-distance-between-any-2-elements . Will dupe close that one into this.

Comment: @NiklasB. There's another version where the objective doesn't separate so easily -- maybe `A[i] + A[j] - |i - j|`. I remember answering that one.

Comment: The question would be clearer with an example. Please could you share an example?

Comment: @NiklasB. `i > j` can make a difference because it forbids `i == j` therefore we can't optimize f(i) and h(j) independently

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible:

- Create an array and fill it with A[i]+i for each i
- Create another array and fill it with A[j] - j for each j
- Get the indexes with the highest I[maxI] and J[maxJ]
- return A[maxI] + A[maxJ] + maxI - maxJ

There you go, O(n)!

Comment: Could u elaborate on second last step.

Comment: No need to create new arrays FWIW

Comment: @Niklas right, no need for two Arrays, but it is a LOT more readable code, and you can debug it way better if you find a mistake a some point. So unless you really need to compute that maximum about 100'000'000 you won't need to do micro optimizations that mess up your code.

Comment: @Sumeet See edited Post. Just Loop through These new Arrays to find the index with the Maximum value.

Comment: This solution has two main faults, first, you need two arrays to store unnecessary data when it only needs two indexes `maxI` and `maxJ`, second, this solution will give wrong answer, when  `maxJ > maxI`, so the answer for pair (maxI, maxJ) should be `A[maxI] + A[maxJ] + maxJ - maxI`. And it cannot handle the case when `maxI = maxJ`

Comment: Third, can you demonstrate how this solution can be debugged better?

Comment: First: thats the reason you can debug it better! You wanna know from where mistakes come if there are any! Second: I don't see a problem there, it will work just fine, there is no special case handling needed according to the post. Third => See first

Comment: So how do you handle the case A = [1,1,100] ? maxI = 2 and maxJ = 2 ? The reason your solution can debug better is having an additional array? I don't get it? Can you explain more?

Comment: Okay, point for you, since the op asked for two elements... Still, yes, it's debugable better, since you can look at the actual arrays he used to calculate the stuff. Anyway, you get my vote since your code seems to be perfectly fine (apart from Stefs suggestion)

Answer (score 11):

For each index i, we only need to know one `index` that maximize the sum `A[i] + A[index] + (i - index) = A[i] + i + (A[index] - index)`. Which mean, we only need to maintain an `index`, which `A[index] - index` is maximum.

```java
int index = 0;
int result = 0;

for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
    int total = A[i] + i + A[index] - index;
    result = max(result, total);
    if(A[i] - i > A[index] - index){
        index = i;
    }
}
return result;
```

Comment: You can't seriously consider a solution that stores two giant arrays better then a solution that tracks one integer.

Comment: @Stef It depends on the use. No matter what, they are basically the same approach, one more useful for huge arrays in the order 10^6, the other one better debugable. Since he did not mention that he had to go through massive arrays, I wrote the debuggable version.

Comment: @xXliolauXx having an additional array doesn't mean debug better.

Comment: I did not downvote but your code assumes the result is at least 0 - I don't see that in the problem specs.

Answer (score 5):

wonderful soln...Pham...thank you.
more readable soln could be...

```
    int sumP = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int sumQ = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
        sumP = Math.max(A[i] - i, sumP);
        sumQ = Math.max(A[i] + i, sumQ);
    }
    return sumP + sumQ;
```

Comment: Excellent answer can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

This is the most accurate solving method that passed the test at 100%.`

```
var sumP = MIN_VALUE*2;
var sumQ = MIN_VALUE*2;
for(var i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
    sumP = Math.max(A[i] - i, sumP);
    sumQ = Math.max(A[i] + i, sumQ);
}
return sumP + sumQ;
```

Comment: Sorry that when I edited, I didn't notice it was in JavaScript. I was thinking about Java. And no way to edit back because it claims "edit must be longer than 6 chars." So please reverse it to the version you had. Sorry again.